# SparkOnHBase: NullPointerException during build tests "distributedScan"

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hbase

I'm quite new to Hadoop, Spark and HBase. I was trying to build the [SparkOnHBase](https://github.com/tmalaska/SparkOnHBase) library by `mvn clean package` (Apache Maven 3.3.3)

But I encountered the following failed test during the build:

```
- distributedScan to test HBase client *** FAILED ***
java.lang.NullPointerException:
at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.reverseDns(DNS.java:92)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.reverseDNS(TableInputFormatBase.java:228)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.getSplits(TableInputFormatBase.java:191)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.getPartitions(NewHadoopRDD.scala:98)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:205)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:203)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:203)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.getPartitions(MappedRDD.scala:28)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:205)
...
```

I'm using Hadoop 2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557 (but I can't sudo, need to ask for help).

Any idea how to fix the error?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use SparkOnHBase to integrate Spark & HBase in Cloudera Hadoop Distribution then follow these steps

1. Add Cloudera Repository in your pom.xml file

   ```
   <repositories>
       <repository>
           <id>cloudera</id>
           <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
       </repository>
   </repositories>
   ```
2. Add dependency in your pom.xml

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.cloudera</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-hbase</artifactId>
       <version>0.0.2-clabs</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. Write code to perform GET/PUT/SCAN operations on HBase using Spark